# ksoap2 Android only working on 4.0.x

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Im using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar to talk to a soap web service. This works perfectly on a device running android 4.0.4, returning the expected response. However on every other device i try it on (2.1, 2.2 etc) it throws the following exception:

```
06-13 12:16:34.154: E/Soap(849): unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT �������������`I�...@1:18 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43d66f08) 
06-13 12:16:34.154: E/Soap(849): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT �������������`I�...@1:18 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43d66f08)
```

Activity code:

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "TopGoalScorers";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/TopGoalScorers";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu";
private static final String URL = "http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
    propertyInfo.setName("iTopN");
    propertyInfo.setValue("5");
    propertyInfo.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(propertyInfo);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;

    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Log.d("Soap", "Finished Call");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Soap", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        Log.e("Soap", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Any ideas what the problem could be? I've tried setting the dotNet flag to true but that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

David

Comment: Hi @David if you still facing this issue can you kindly post your httpTransport Request and Response DUMP .

Answer (score 2):

I have currently the same issue. I solved it using the ksoap2 library version 2.5.7. Hope it helps. It must be a bug on 2.6.5 with the received encoding.

Comment: See ksoap2 Issue 124 here
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=124

Comment: No problem. Make sure you mark this thread as resolved if all your doubts were cleared. Cheers.